# Xcode how to get ints between view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode

I have barely done anything in Objective C. I want to make apps for the iPhone. My goal is to make a very small app just as a first. The only thing I need to know is how I can see what the value of my isn't is from another view.

I have Googled public variables, int between view controllers with etc. I tried everything, hundreds of websites and nothing worked

I can't follow web pages and other Stack Overflow questions. Please just take the time it takes to find the right link to type out the code. It really helps.

Comment: People will down vote not because you are a noob but because you haven't provided anything that you have tried or attempted to try to achieve what you want first. Posts like these sound like "I want to do blah but don't want to bother figuring it out so just tell me how to do it". Add some more details and help will come

Comment: you're almost certainly looking for "container views", @jaydz49 "Everything" is a container view in iOS now. It is quite easy but here is a very long essay about it .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884  Note that if you're literally just starting, it's unlikely you NEED differnt views (ie, container views).  Simply, put everything "on the one scene". It's just that easy, really.

Answer (score 1):

In the header file, you need to create getter methods for the variables you want to get. See: [Objective-C getter/ setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616581/objective-c-getter-setter)

Alternatively, you can pass the value into the view controller as part of its initialization.

And as mentioned in another answer, follow Rays stuff, he has great material, I've done through a lot of his material.